# What might slow down an android httpurlconnection through wifi

Tags: android, wifi, httpurlconnection

My android app is connecting to my server using httpurlconnect. When I connect from home it takes only half second to get response. But when I connect from office, it takes more than 5 seconds to get response. 
The speed test result for both wifi are similar, ping& download, except upload is much faster in office. 
Steps I tried:
1 change office wireless router to less traffic channel. No difference.
2 using static DNS on router/ android phone. No difference .
3 it takes similar time to download big data or small data
I believe this is a network issue. Just want to know what factor might slow the connection down? Is there anything  I can do to improve the speed from android app itself?

Comment: This is clearly a network connection problem, do you make the speed test using your phone or computer?

Comment: network speed are not stable or linear if i should say... which means it goes up and falls down sometimes due to soo many reasons.. so 5 secs? dat shouldnt be a problem..

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Speed test was through tablet. I understand network speed could be up and down. But I tested lots of times. Alway around 5/6 sec at office and half sec at home. The app is used to do transaction, 5 sec for network is not acceptable. Any idea?

Comment: Also, I tested from friends' home,  as fast as mine. But it's slow at both of our office location. All locations have high speed internet, and one of our office is using same ISP as my home. I brought my wireless router to office, with same setting, the speed down to 6 seconds.